# SharePoint 2019 on premise - User Profile Property - Need new Property

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, properties

We currently have an AD Attribute named Division which is used to pull information from AD into SP.
The Property Settings has the Type set to **string** and **length** is 25. This has just recently become a problem when the contents of the String for this property have now become greater than the string length.

We know we are able to create a new property to replace the older one. I am gathering once the **new** property is created we add **Property Mapping for Synchronization**.

What we need to know is can we remove the mapping from the **old** property and / or deleted the old property once the new property is setup? And will this impact the current setup and display?

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We found that that we **could not** change the original property but we could recreate the Managed Property **BUT** it did need a new name.

We did delete the old property and the new one was created with the same parameters - changes included the increased string length and a new property name.

Once the new managed property was set under the UPS area and the new mapping added - all that was needed was for the Search Service Application: Managed Properties > **NewlyCreatedProperty** to have its Mappings to crawled properties set to the new property name.

We do hope this is a help to someone else.